# Unable to convert ConvLSTM to tflite model

Tags: android, tensorflow

I have a convolutional LSTM model that I am hoping to use on an android app to do real time prediction, however facing some issue converting it to tflite.

```
model = Sequential()
model.add(ConvLSTM2D(filters=64, kernel_size=(1,3), activation='relu', input_shape=(n_steps, 1, n_length, n_features)))
model.add(Dropout(0.5))
model.add(Flatten())
model.add(Dense(100, activation='relu'))
model.add(Dense(n_classes, activation='softmax'))

model.compile(loss='categorical_crossentropy', optimizer='adam', metrics=['accuracy'])

model.summary()
```

Everything works fine, however when I try to convert to tflite, I get the following error:

```
converter = tf.lite.TFLiteConverter.from_keras_model(model)
tflite_model = converter.convert()

# Save the model.
with open('model_conv_lstm.tflite', 'wb') as f:
  f.write(tflite_model)

from google.colab import files
files.download('model_conv_lstm.tflite')
```

```
/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/lite/python/convert.py in toco_convert_protos(model_flags_str, toco_flags_str, input_data_str, debug_info_str, enable_mlir_converter)
    313       for error_data in _metrics_wrapper.retrieve_collected_errors():
    314         converter_error.append_error(error_data)
--> 315       raise converter_error
    316 
    317   return _run_toco_binary(model_flags_str, toco_flags_str, input_data_str,

ConverterError: /usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/saved_model/save.py:1315:0: error: 'tf.TensorListReserve' op requires element_shape to be static during TF Lite transformation pass
<unknown>:0: note: loc("StatefulPartitionedCall"): called from
/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/saved_model/save.py:1315:0: error: failed to legalize operation 'tf.TensorListReserve' that was explicitly marked illegal
<unknown>:0: note: loc("StatefulPartitionedCall"): called from
<unknown>:0: error: Lowering tensor list ops is failed. Please consider using Select TF ops and disabling `_experimental_lower_tensor_list_ops` flag in the TFLite converter object. For example, converter.target_spec.supported_ops = [tf.lite.OpsSet.TFLITE_BUILTINS, tf.lite.OpsSet.SELECT_TF_OPS]\n converter._experimental_lower_tensor_list_ops = False
```

I manage to fix the error if I convert the model to tflite using this:

```
# Convert the model.
converter = tf.lite.TFLiteConverter.from_keras_model(model)
converter.target_spec.supported_ops = [tf.lite.OpsSet.TFLITE_BUILTINS, tf.lite.OpsSet.SELECT_TF_OPS]
converter._experimental_lower_tensor_list_ops = False
tflite_model = converter.convert()

# Save the model.
with open('model_conv_lstm.tflite', 'wb') as f:
  f.write(tflite_model)

from google.colab import files
files.download('model_conv_lstm.tflite')
```

However, when I import the tflite model into my android app, it doesn't work anymore and the app crashes each time I load the model. Any ideas what might be the problem?

Comment: Did you manage to get it working?